# How do I optimize a for loop for faster results in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, for-loop, optimization

I've written a piece of code to extract data from a HDF5 file and save into a dataframe that I can export as .csv later. The final data frame effectively has 2.5 million rows and is taking a lot of time to execute.
Is there any way, I can optimize this code so that it can run effectively.

Current runtime is 7.98 minutes!

Ideally I would want to run this program for 48 files like these and expect a faster run time.

Link to source file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1g2fpJHZmD5FflfB4s3BlAoiB5sGISKmg/view

```
import h5py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
#import geopandas as gpd


#%%
f = h5py.File('mer.h5', 'r')

for key in f.keys():
    #print(key) #Names of the root level object names in HDF5 file - can be groups or datasets.
    #print(type(f[key])) # get the object type: usually group or dataset
    ls = list(f.keys())
   



#Get the HDF5 group; key needs to be a group name from above
key ='DHI'
#group = f['OBSERVATION_TIME']

#print("Group")
#print(group)

#for key in ls:
 #data = f.get(key)   
 #dataset1 = np.array(data)

#length=len(dataset1)


masterdf=pd.DataFrame()


data = f.get(key)   
dataset1 = np.array(data)
#masterdf[key]=dataset1


X = f.get('X')
X_1 = pd.DataFrame(X)

Y = f.get('Y')
Y_1 = pd.DataFrame(Y)





#%%


data_df = pd.DataFrame(index=range(len(Y_1)),columns=range(len(X_1)))

for i in data_df.index:
    data_df.iloc[i] = dataset1[0][i]
    
    
#data_df.to_csv("test.csv")


#%%





final = pd.DataFrame(index=range(1616*1616),columns=['X', 'Y','GHI'])


k=0

for y in range(len(Y_1)):
    
    for x in range(len(X_1[:-2])):   #X and Y ranges are not same
        
        final.loc[k,'X'] = X_1[0][x]
        final.loc[k,'Y'] = Y_1[0][y]
        final.loc[k,'GHI'] = data_df.iloc[y,x]
        k=k+1
        # print(k)`
```

Comment: Please make your code here more compact: Remove lines that are not needed (there's a lot commented out), and trim the excessive whitespace.

Comment: @Timus  I have updated the file to give permission for all.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1g2fpJHZmD5FflfB4s3BlAoiB5sGISKmg/view

I used h5py to read the file. Haven't tried pd.read_hdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please try the following (`file.h5` your file):

```py
import pandas as pd
import h5py

with h5py.File("file.h5", "r") as file:
    df_X = pd.DataFrame(file.get("X")[:-2], columns=["X"])
    df_Y = pd.DataFrame(file.get("Y"), columns=["Y"])
    DHI = file.get("DHI")[0][:, :-2].reshape(-1)

final = df_Y.merge(df_X, how="cross").assign(DHI=DHI)[["X", "Y", "DHI"]]
```

Some explanations:

- First read the data with key `X` into a dataframe `df_X` with one column `X`, except for the last 2 data points.
- Then read the full data with key `Y` into a dataframe `df_Y` with one column `Y`.
- Then get the data with key `DHI` and take the first element `[0]` (there are no more): Result is a NumpPy array with 2 dimensions, a matrix. Now remove the last two columns (`[:, :-2]`) and [reshape](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) the matrix into an 1-dimensional array, in the order you are looking for (`order="C"` is default). The result is the column `DHI` of your `final` dataframe.
- Finally take the cross product of `df_Y` and `df_X` (`y` is your outer dimension in the loop) via [`.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge.html) with `how="cross"`, add the `DHI` column, and rearrange the columns in the order you want.

Comment: That code worked like magic. Could you please explain how you did it? I'm not able to understand how you did it.  Was my approach wrong?

Also another query I have is that these X, Y values I want to convert and save as X2,Y2 using a library called PyProj. I used the same loop style to achieve it, but is there anway to do it faster like the way you did it? Code is as follows:

       `
        x2,y2=transform(inProj,outProj,X_1[0][x],Y_1[0][y],always_xy=True)
        final.loc[k,'X2'] = x2
        final.loc[k,'Y2'] = y2
        `

Comment: @RishikeshSreehari I've added some explanations and hope they help. (I also adjusted the solution slightly, since I realised that there's no need to transpose the `DHI` matrix when the standard reshape order (`"C"`) is used.)

Comment: @RishikeshSreehari Your approach wasn't _wrong_ if it produced the correct result. But as mentioned in the other answer: NumPy and Pandas offer vectorized methods that are way faster than looping.

Comment: @RishikeshSreehari Unfortunately I have never worked with `PyProj`, so I can't really help here :(

Answer (score 1):

we can optimize loops by vectorizing operations. this is one/two orders of magnitude faster than their pure python equivalents(especially in numerical computations). vectorization is something we can get with NumPy. it is a library with efficient data structures designed to hold matrix data.

Comment: Please be specific, i.e. apply what you're proposing to the provided code (as you can see, OP is already using NumPy/Pandas, but not necessarily in an optimal manner).

Comment: Could you please elaborate your answer? I'm thinking on how to apply in this case's scenario, basically the last for loop.